# How i can access the "isComplete()" method of range picker in my template?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to access the method `isComplete()` of [mat-date-range-picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) in my template:

```
<div *ngIf="!picker.isComplete()">
    You should select the range date
</div>
<mat-date-range-picker
   #picker
 ></mat-date-range-picker>
```

I'm facing this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'isComplete' does not exist on type
> 'MatDateRangePicker

```
Environment
Angular:
"@angular/core": "~10.0.14",
CDK/Material:
"@angular/material": "^10.1.3",
```

This is exactly what i need, but how i can acess this function?

In docs, i finded this method `isComplete()`:

> "Checks whether the current selection is complete. In the case of a
> single date selection, this is true if the current selection is not
> null."

Comment: The doc says about  `MatSingleDateSelectionModel` not about `MatDateRangePicker`

Comment: @yurzui you are right, do you know if there's a way to access MatSingleDateSelectionModel in template?

Comment: `$any(picker)._model.isComplete()`